# Preload key requests in Svelte/Sapper project

Tags: performance, svelte, lighthouse, sapper

I'm running [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) on a production website built with [Svelte/Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev/) in order to measure its performance. It seems like the biggest opportunity, according to Lighthouse, is preloading key requests.

[image]

I found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/919) about it but I don't know how to make Svelte/Sapper automatically preload the key resources, namely the JavaScript and CSS bundles. I cannot just hard-code them because they have different hashes after each build.

For example, I want these to be included in the `head` tag of the resulting HTML:

```
<link rel="preload" href="styles.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="/client/chunk.3065f5a7.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href=/client/index.eb6a9ec4.js" as="script">
```

How do I make Svelte/Sapper automatically add `<link type="preload" />` meta tags for key resources?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard question to answer without some understanding of your project structure, however, [Sapper does have the ability to preload resources](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading).  Was something like this what you were looking for?

Taken directly from the link above:

```js
<script context="module">
    export async function preload(page, session) {
        const { slug } = page.params;

        const res = await this.fetch(`blog/${slug}.json`);
        const article = await res.json();

        return { article };
    }
</script>
<script>
    export let article;
</script>
<h1>{article.title}</h1>
```

EDIT: APR 7,2021
This looks to be resolved as of Sapper 0.28.10, according to [Sapper GitHub Issue#1576](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1576), from OCT 2020.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! However, I'm looking for a solution that will automatically add `<link type="preload" />` meta tags for key resources.

Comment: According to the GH issue linked off of the one you gave, this should be working as of 0.28.10

Comment: But it's not. And if I understand it correctly when looking at it again, it works if you export your app as a static website which won't work for me.